# .git/config permission denied when trying to add remote on ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, bitbucket, file-permissions, user-permissions

I am trying to add an extra remote to an existing git project so I can push code to a secondary bitbucket repository using the **git remote add user2 git@bitbucket.org:...** ,  but I am getting the following error:

> error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied

It is an old project so I am not sure how it was originally setup, but it does seem like it may have been installed as root.

I tried checking the file permissions for .git and .git/config and I can see it belongs to www-data.  My current user is part of the www-data group, but I still get the same error.

I also checked for .git/config.lock file just in case it was blocking but there isn't one.

I am not a fan of using sudo with .git, so I am wondering if someone can give me some best practice advice on how deal with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making everything owned by a group is the way to go, but you must 
make sure it everything has both group write permissions and every file is in the `www-data` group recursively:

```
  sudo chown -R :www-data /path/to/git/repo
  sudo chmod -R g+w /path/to/git/repo
```

Then run your git commands.

Comment: recursive settings was my issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to use `sudo` with `git` if your permissions are set up correctly.

This sounds like a basic permissions issue. You found you're part of the group, but you also need the file to have group `rw` permissions if you are banking on access via group perms, e.g. `chmod g+rw .git/config`. Either that or you need to be the owner of the files in question, also with `rw`.

Since you mention `www-data` as the group, it makes me wonder if you're on a server. If you're using a server OS such as CentOS, you likely have SELinux running, in which case that's another layer of permissions you need to deal with. Use `ls -alZ` to see SELinux perms if present.

Comment: Yes, its a server (ubuntu 14.04)